# PHP - Create text through implode vs substr

Tags: php, substr, implode

Here is situation :
I'll use foreach to get some value , and now I can

1. save as txt `$txt .= $vlaue."&";` , but need to delete last '&' so use `$txt = substr( $txt , 0 , -1);`

or

2. save as array `$txt[] = $vlaue;` , and use `implode( "&" , $txt);`

Two method will get the same text , but which is better?
(Consider speed and memory usage?)

Comment: If you use `implode()`, you will no longer have to loop through each items of your object, because this functions takes an array in parameter. So you could say in order to reduce the number of line of code, `implode()` is more interesting, but I would not dare say it is faster because it will still loop through your object.

Comment: PHP is a high-level interpreted language, this level of optimisation is pretty academic... unless you're looping through gigabytes of text maybe.

Comment: Get value via foreach can't avoid ,I will get specific value from another array;

Answer (score 0):

Preferably neither.

If you're building a query string, use `http_build_query` as it will also take care of proper variable escaping for you.

Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Easy to read code is more valuable than performant but unmaintainable code. If you have big strings and performance **actually** matters, `ob_start` + `echo` + `ob_end_clean` is approximately twice as fast as both (it avoids a lot of memory reallocations) for any non-trivial sized output.

Comment: No , I am not creat a query string , that's a website display from database.